# Read Store's Initial State in Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Initial state in a Redux app can be set in two ways:

- pass it as the second argument to `createStore` ([docs link](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html))
- pass it as the first argument to your (sub-)reducers ([docs link](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html))

If you pass initial state to your store, how do you read that state from the store and make it the first argument in your reducers?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

> ### TL;DR
>
> Without `combineReducers()` or similar manual code, `initialState` always wins over `state = ...` in the reducer because the `state` passed to the reducer *is* `initialState` and *is not* `undefined`, so the ES6 argument syntax doesn't get applied in this case.
>
> With `combineReducers()` the behavior is more nuanced. Those reducers whose state is specified in `initialState` will receive that `state`. Other reducers will receive `undefined` *and because of that* will fall back to the `state = ...` default argument they specify.
>
> **In general, `initialState` wins over the state specified by the reducer. This lets reducers specify initial data that makes sense *to them* as default arguments, but also allows loading existing data (fully or partially) when you're hydrating the store from some persistent storage or the server.**

First let's consider a case where you have a single reducer.
Say you don't use `combineReducers()`.

Then your reducer might look like this:

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT': return state + 1;
  case 'DECREMENT': return state - 1;
  default: return state;
  }
}
```

Now let's say you create a store with it.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
let store = createStore(counter);
console.log(store.getState()); // 0
```

The initial state is zero. Why?   Because the second argument to `createStore` was `undefined`. This is the `state` passed to your reducer the first time. When Redux initializes it dispatches a “dummy” action to fill the state. So your `counter` reducer was called with `state` equal to `undefined`. **This is exactly the case that “activates” the default argument.** Therefore, `state` is now `0` as per the default `state` value (`state = 0`). This state (`0`) will be returned.

Let's consider a different scenario:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
let store = createStore(counter, 42);
console.log(store.getState()); // 42
```

Why is it `42`, and not `0`, this time? Because `createStore` was called with `42` as the second argument. This argument becomes the `state` passed to your reducer along with the dummy action. **This time, `state` is not undefined (it's `42`!), so ES6 default argument syntax has no effect.** The `state` is `42`, and `42` is returned from the reducer.

---

Now let's consider a case where you use `combineReducers()`.
You have two reducers:

```
function a(state = 'lol', action) {
  return state;
}

function b(state = 'wat', action) {
  return state;
}
```

The reducer generated by `combineReducers({ a, b })` looks like this:

```
// const combined = combineReducers({ a, b })
function combined(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    a: a(state.a, action),
    b: b(state.b, action)
  };
}
```

If we call `createStore` without the `initialState`, it's going to initialize the `state` to `{}`. Therefore, `state.a` and `state.b` will be `undefined` by the time it calls `a` and `b` reducers. **Both `a` and `b` reducers will receive `undefined` as *their* `state` arguments, and if they specify default `state` values, those will be returned.** This is how the combined reducer returns a `{ a: 'lol', b: 'wat' }` state object on the first invocation.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
let store = createStore(combined);
console.log(store.getState()); // { a: 'lol', b: 'wat' }
```

Let's consider a different scenario:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
let store = createStore(combined, { a: 'horse' });
console.log(store.getState()); // { a: 'horse', b: 'wat' }
```

Now I specified the `initialState` as the argument to `createStore()`. The state returned from the combined reducer *combines* the initial state I specified for the `a` reducer with the `'wat'` default argument specified that `b` reducer chose itself.

Let's recall what the combined reducer does:

```
// const combined = combineReducers({ a, b })
function combined(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    a: a(state.a, action),
    b: b(state.b, action)
  };
}
```

In this case, `state` was specified so it didn't fall back to `{}`. It was an object with `a` field equal to `'horse'`, but without the `b` field. This is why the `a` reducer received `'horse'` as its `state` and gladly returned it, but the `b` reducer received `undefined` as its `state` and thus returned *its idea* of the default `state` (in our example, `'wat'`). This is how we get `{ a: 'horse', b: 'wat' }` in return.

---

To sum this up, if you stick to Redux conventions and return the initial state from reducers when they're called with `undefined` as the `state` argument (the easiest way to implement this is to specify the `state` ES6 default argument value), you're going to have a nice useful behavior for combined reducers. **They will prefer the corresponding value in the `initialState` object you pass to the `createStore()` function, but if you didn't pass any, or if the corresponding field is not set, the default `state` argument specified by the reducer is chosen instead.** This approach works well because it provides both initialization and hydration of existing data, but lets individual reducers reset their state if their data was not preserved. Of course you can apply this pattern recursively, as you can use `combineReducers()` on many levels, or even compose reducers manually by calling reducers and giving them the relevant part of the state tree.

Comment: Thanks for the great detail - exactly what I was looking for. The flexibility of your API here is brilliant. The part I wasn't seeing is that the "child" reducer will understand which piece of the initial state belongs to it based on the key used in `combineReducers`. Thank you again very much.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Dan. If I'm digesting your answer correctly, you're saying that it would be best to set an initial state through a reducer's action type? For example, GET_INITIAL_STATE and call a dispatch to that action type in, let's say, a componentDidMount callback?

Comment: @ConAntonakos No, I don’t mean this. I mean choosing the initial state right where you define the reducer, e.g. `function counter(state = 0, action)` or `function visibleIds(state = [], action)`.

Comment: @DanAbramov - Got it. What are thoughts on initializing data, though? Would what I described above work? Sorry if I'm repeating anything; I'd be happy to read another discussion if it exists. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: It would technically work but your views should avoid knowing the exact state structure—it would be hard to refactor later. Even for reading the data, it’s best to use selectors so views stay agnostic.

Comment: @DanAbramov:  using the second argument in createstore(), how can i rehydrate the state upon SPA page reload with the last stored state in redux instead of the intial values. I guess i'm asking how can i cache the entire store and preserve it on reload and pass it to the createstore function.

Comment: @jasan: Use localStorage. https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage?course=building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

Comment: This is just brilliant write-up for redux beginners. Basically i was looking to load an initial bunch of data for my app, and now i know, the best way to do this would be to create data in a  seed reducer.

Comment: @DanAbramov i'm curious how it makes sense to say that a reducer should be in charge of its own state shape in order to allow it to change without refactoring outside the reducer and at the same time allow a persisted state tree to be passed from local storage or similar. how is the persisted tree any less "aware" of the state shape than someone building an initial tree by hand in code for example?

Comment: @SterlingCamden not sure if you ever got an answer but for others, I believe Dan mentions something related [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1189#issuecomment-168025590) and the tl;dr is you want the reducers to be self-sufficient and reusable. If you are building the state tree by hand, that is prone to errors -- instead reuse the reducer you created. In his egghead lesson, he serializes the result of the state tree from localStorage and it's guaranteed to be of right state shape because it came from the reducer itself. Someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not if you change a refactor the implementation of the reducer which is the same reason you don’t want code that uses the state to know its shape. I would say storing initial state is fundamentally an anti pattern unless you could somehow store a version of reducer as well. Better not to use initial state at all and store pieces that you could get into state on load via actions imho

Comment: This answer is misleading, because it implies that the default state argument is only used if you don't pass any corresponding field in createState. However, combineReducers will *always* call your reducer function with an undefined argument to "verify" it, completely ignoring what's passed in createState. When dealing with strongly typed stores especially, this is a huge pain because it requires you to duplicate "initialization" logic between the client and the server, and requires you to have an "empty" store state, which is pointless because it'll never be used.

Answer (score 6):

In a nutshell: it's Redux the one who passes the initial state to the reducers, you don't need to do anything.

When you call `createStore(reducer, [initialState])` you are letting Redux know what is the initial state to be passed to the reducer when the first action comes in.

The second option you mention, applies only in case you didn't pass an initial state when creating the store. i.e.

`function todoApp(state = initialState, action)`

state will only be initialised if there was no state passed by Redux

Comment: Thanks for responding - in the case of reducer composition, if you've applied initial state to the store, how do you tell the child/sub reducer which part of the initial state tree it owns? For example, if you have a `menuState`, how do I tell the menu reducer to read the value of `state.menu` from the store and use that as its initial state?

Comment: Thanks, but my question must be unclear. I'll wait to see if others respond before editing.

Answer (score 1):

> how do you read that state from the store and make it the first argument in your reducers?

combineReducers() do the job for you.
The first way to write it is not really helpfull :

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ todos, users })
```

But the other one, that is equivalent is more clear :

```
function rootReducer(state, action) {
   todos: todos(state.todos, action),
   users: users(state.users, action)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your request (which I understood as initializing reducers while passing intialState and returning that state)

This is how we do it (warning: copied from Typescript code).

The gist of it is the `if(!state)` test in the mainReducer(factory) function

```
function getInitialState(): MainState {

     return {
         prop1:                 'value1',
         prop1:                 'value2',
         ...        
     }
}



const reducer = combineReducers(
    {
        main:     mainReducer( getInitialState() ),
        ...
    }
)



const mainReducer = ( initialState: MainState ): Reducer => {

    return ( state: MainState, action: Action ): MainState => {

        if ( !state ) {
            return initialState
        }

        console.log( 'Main reducer action: ', action ) 

        switch ( action.type ) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```