# How to correctly update my initialState in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have an initialState:

```
export default {
  dashboards: [],
  dashboardContent: []
};
```

Which I would like to update via the reducer after an action dispatch like so:

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function dashboardContentReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { dashboardContent: action.dashboardContent });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function dashboardReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { dashboards: action.dashboards });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

After dispatching the actions, when I look into my store, I see that it has been updated, but one level too deep:

```
{
  dashboards: {
    dashboards: [/* array received from reducer */],
    dashboardContent: []
  },
  dashboardContent: {
    dashboards: [],
    dashboardContent: [/* array received from reducer */]
  }
}
```

How do I make it so that it turns into my intended which should simply be:

```
{
  dashboards: [/* payload received from reducer */],
  dashboardContent: [/* payload received from reducer */]
}
```

EDIT:

Here is how the payload looks.

For dashboardContent:

```
[
  {
    application: 'Company News',
    site: 'Home',
    lastUpdated: 'Jun 1, 2016 10:30',
    location: 'Asbury',
    views: 123451,
    individuals: 2345
  },
  {
    application: 'Company News',
    site: 'Home',
    lastUpdated: 'Jun 1, 2016 10:30',
    location: 'Asbury',
    views: 123451,
    individuals: 2345
  },
  {
    application: 'Company News',
    site: 'Home',
    lastUpdated: 'Jun 1, 2016 10:30',
    location: 'Asbury',
    views: 123451,
    individuals: 2345
  },
  {
    application: 'Company News',
    site: 'Home',
    lastUpdated: 'Jun 1, 2016 10:30',
    location: 'Asbury',
    views: 123451,
    individuals: 2345
  },
  {
    application: 'Company News',
    site: 'Home',
    lastUpdated: 'Jun 1, 2016 10:30',
    location: 'Asbury',
    views: 123451,
    individuals: 2345
  }
];
```

for dashboards:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Overview",
    template: "main",
    category: "Main",
    sort: {},
    filter: {
    loginType: "All Accounts",
    Pivot: "location",
    pivotValue: 1
    },
    priority: 0,
    readonly: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Top Applications",
    template: "application-usage",
    category: "Application Usage",
    sort: {
      first: {
        by: "views",
        direction: "desc"
      },
      second:  {
        By:"individuals",
        direction: "desc"
      }
    },
    filter: {
      application: 0,
      Pivot: location,
      pivotValue: 1
    },
    priority: 1,
    readonly: true,
    createdDate: "2016-12-29T16:37:11.62Z",
    updatedDate: "2016-12-29T16:37:11.62Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe the action payload is not an array, but an object with same shape as the initial state.

Comment: That wouldn't be the case. I'll update the post to include how the payload looks.

Comment: Try this code if it works : `return Object.assign({}, state, action.dashboards);`

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Comment: Are you using `combineReducers`? Because that will create two distinct state objects

Comment: Yes. I am using combineReducers. How do you mean "two distinct state objects"? I thought redux was only 1 single global state object.

Comment: Not with `combineReducers`. For example, `combineReducers({ dashboard, dashboardContent });` will produce a state object like: `{ dashboard: { /* Accessible to dashboard reducer */ }, dashboardContent: { /* Accessible to dashboardContent reducer */} }`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using two different reducers, and you are aware of the `initialState` , why not modify your reducers as

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function dashboardContent(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and the other one as

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function dashboard(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Well, i have changed the names of the reducers, but while using`combineReducers` the naming doesnt matter anyway.   As you can always do.

```
combineReducers({
  dashboardContent:dashboardContentReducersWhichHasBeenGivenAWeirdName,
  dashboard:dashboardReducerAgainNamedWeird
})
```

Your state will be created as `{dashboard:[],dashboardContent:[]}`

By this way you can avoid the updates at the wrong level.
also i'd recommened taking  a look at the [explanation here by Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749759/read-stores-initial-state-in-redux-reducer/33791942#33791942) , it explains in detail how `createStore` creates the state based on your reducers, also how intialState takes precedence.

Comment: Why `state = []` in the first and `state = initialState` in the second?

Comment: Also, how do you mean combineReducers naming doesn't matter? What does this imply?

Comment: @iggy2012 Sry , that was a typo, expanded the answer a bit. !

Answer (score 1):

From the [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) docs:

> The resulting reducer calls every child reducer, and gathers their
>   results into a single state object. The shape of the state object
>   matches the keys of the passed reducers.
>
> Consequently, the state object will look like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   reducer1: ...
>   reducer2: ...
> }
> ```

So when using it, in order for two reducers to share state, you need to create a single reducer like so:

```
import initialState from './initialState';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function dashboardReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { dashboards: action.dashboards });
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { dashboardContent: action.dashboardContent });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Or if you want to keep the logic separate for whatever reason, you can use the [`reduce-reducers`](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) library:

```
import reduceReducers from "reduce-reducers";
import dashboardReducer from "./dashboardReducer";
import dashboardContentReducer from "./dashboardContentReducer";

const combined = reduceReducers(dashboardReducer, dashboardContentReducer);

createStore(combineReducers({ dashboard: combined }));
```

That way you will have a state object:

```
{
    dashboard: {
        dashboards: []
        dashboardContent: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the inner `dashboards` and not the outer one. Try

```
export default function dashboardReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARDS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                dashboards: Object.assign({},state.dashboards,{dashboards: action.dashboards}
             });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and

```
export default function dashboardContentReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_CONTENT_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                dashboards: Object.assign({},state.dashboards,{dashboardContent: action.dashboardContent}
             });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```