# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (React-Redux) Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have problem with react-redux. I create a checkbox with redux, but i have a problem that my data=[array] back data=[array] but not [new array] with new props "completed". When i use this function on reducer, i have problem with my ComponentBike `this.props.state.map` inspector says: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong, people?

This is my reducer:

```
import { TOGGLE_CHECKBOX } from '../actions/actions'

export default function reducer(state = [], action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX':
        return {
            ...state,
            checkbox: state.checkbox.map(check => check.id === action.id ?
                {...check, completed: action.completed} :
            check
            )
        };
}
}
```

This is my action:

```
export const TOGGLE_CHECKBOX = 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX';

export function toggleCheckbox(id) {
 return  {
  type: TOGGLE_CHECKBOX,
  completed: true,
  id
}
}
```

My Container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleCheckbox } from '../../redux/actions/actions';
import ComponentBike from '../../components/bikes/info-bikes';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
     state: state
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    onChange: (id) => dispatch(toggleCheckbox(id)),
  }
}
const CheckboxContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentBike);

export default CheckboxContainer;
```

My store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducers/reducer';

export const initialState = {
'checkbox': [
{
        'id': 1,
        'label': 'Sport',
        'completed': false
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'label': 'Cross',
        'completed': false
    }
]

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

export default store;
```

and my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '../../../../Checkbox';

export default class ComponentBike extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
     this.props.onChange(this.props.id);
}

render () {
    return <div className="window">
                    <Container>
                        <div className="all-checks">
                            {this.props.state.map(check =>
                                <Checkbox
                                    key={check.id}
                                    id={check.id}
                                    label={check.label}
                                    checked={check.completed}
                                    onChange={this.handleClick(check.id)}
                                />
                            )}
            </div>
```

I would be very grateful for help with this problem.

Comment: Your state isn't an array, it's an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your `state` object, you can see the checkboxes are inside the `checkbox` property:

```
export const initialState = {
  'checkbox': [
```

So that would be the array you need to loop through in the render function (`this.props.state.checkbox.map`):

```
<div className="all-checks">
  {this.props.state.checkbox.map(check =>
    <Checkbox
      key={check.id}
      id={check.id}
      label={check.label}
      checked={check.completed}
      onChange={this.handleClick(check.id)}
    />
  )}
</div>
```

---

## Update

I see a few other problems that might be causing some trouble. I renamed `checkbox` to `checkboxes` since it's an array. Here are some changes I would make below:

### reducer

initialState goes better with the reducer, because at some point you might have multiple reducers that can each have their own initial state ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791942/1633510)). Also make sure you have a `default` case in the switch statement:

```
const initialState = {
  checkboxes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      label: 'Sport',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'Cross',
      completed: false
    }
  ]
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX':
    return {
      ...state,
      checkboxes: state.checkboxes.map(check => check.id === action.id ?
        {...check, completed: action.completed} :
        check
      )
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

### store

```
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

### container

Pass the part state you need explicitly:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
     checkboxes: state.checkboxes
  };
}
```

### component

`onChange` needs an arrow function to pass the correct id

```
handleClick(id) {
  this.props.onChange(id);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="window">
      <Container>
        <div className="all-checks">
          {this.props.checkboxes.map(check => (
            <Checkbox
              key={check.id}
              id={check.id}
              label={check.label}
              checked={check.completed}
              onChange={() => this.handleClick(check.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Update 2

Needed to add `default` to the switch statement in the reducer.

```
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX':
    return {
      ...state,
      checkboxes: state.checkboxes.map(check => check.id === action.id ?
        {...check, completed: action.completed} :
        check
      )
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
```

See working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/t7smqtbL/1/

Comment: Thanks for this, but inspector now says: "Cannot read property 'checkbox' of undefined" /../components/bikes/info-bikes.js:66

Comment: @AudiQuattro1992 added some more info and changes that might help you

Comment: I dont understand, where is my trouble. Now insperctor give me new issue: "Cannot read property 'checkboxes' of undefined" /CheckboxContainer/
         checkboxes: state.checkboxes What is wrong?

Comment: @AudiQuattro1992 looks like it was causing an error because there was no `default` in the switch statement. Try adding that and it should work. I also added a working jsfiddle demo

Comment: THANK YOU MAN !!! From my heart,
god bless you and your family!))) Thank you very much!